# Authentication with DelegatingHandler in aspnet webapi

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-web-api2, owin, owin-middleware

I have a JwtAuthentication MessageHandler (from DelegatingHandler) implemented on a webapi project. All my allowanonymous webapi are now getting verified for the authentication. Does it mean MessageHandlers will not consider the allowanonymous attribute at all and process all incoming requests for authentication?

How do I skip authentication for allowanonymous webapi method calls for authentication when we have an authentication message-handler added to the pipeline. Please suggest.

Comment: Please show your code, see [FAQ]s and [ask]